# Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka with a recordFilterStrategy.

```java
@Bean("manualImmediateListenerContainerFactory")
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object>> manualImmediateListenerContainerFactory(
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(9999999);
        factory.setBatchListener(false);
        //配置手动提交offset
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.setAckDiscarded(true);
        factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(new RecordFilterStrategy<Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            public boolean filter(ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> consumerRecord) {
                Shipment shipment = (Shipment) consumerRecord.value();
                return shipment.getType().contains("YAW");
            }
        });
        return factory;
    }
```

Here I have did factory.setAckDiscarded(true). When it received a message which should be discarded. It will try to ack discarded message. Then it will get an exception like below.
I already increased max.poll.interval.ms and decreased maximum size of batches.
Any hints will be highly appreciated!
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

Comment: This only happys when it receive messages which should be discarded. When message's content is wanted and passed to listener. It will be acknowledged successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in kafka console. It was continuesly prepare for rebalanceing. Basic i think the issue is caused by kafka broker is not stable except the spring application code has the issue.